# Defined a Goji route with bound parameter but getting 404

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goji

I've got a Google App Engine app using Goji and defined the following routes:

```
func init() {
    mux := web.New()
    http.Handle("/api/list", mux)

    mux.Use(middleware.EnvInit)
    mux.Use(middleware.Logger)

    mux.Get( "/api/list",       list.HandleListGetAll)
    mux.Post("/api/list",       list.HandleListNewList)
    mux.Get( "/api/list/:id",   list.HandleListGetSingle)
}
```

I can GET and POST to /api/list but GETing /api/list/0 just results in a 404, I think from Goji itself.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 isn't being returned by Goji—any 404 from Goji should be logged to console (stdout) by the `Logger` middleware. The upstream handler passing requests to the Goji router is bouncing anything that isn't `/api/list`.

You can fix this with a more lenient match:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web/middleware"
)

func main() {
    mux := web.New()
    http.Handle("/api/", mux)

    mux.Use(middleware.EnvInit)
    mux.Use(middleware.Logger)

    mux.Get("/api/list/:id", debugHandler)
    mux.Get("/api/list", debugHandler)
    mux.Post("/api/list", debugHandler)

    // If Goji's router 404's, we should call our custom handler, and it
    // should also be apparent in the logs.
    mux.NotFound(notFoundHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func debugHandler(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", r.URL.Path)
}

func notFoundHandler(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Goji 404: %s", r.URL.Path), 404)
}
```

Note that I've changed the upstream `http.Handle` to `http.Handle("/api/", mux)` to provide a more lenient match. The `net/http` router is very simple and because `/api/list/131313` (e.g. with an id) doesn't match `/api/list` it 404's before it even hits the Goji mux instance you created.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent - that was exactly it. Thanks very much for your help!